# Show that if $f\in L^1_{loc}(\mathbb{R})$ and $f(x)=\frac{1}{2r}\int_{x-r}^{x+r}f(t)dt$ for all $x\in\mathbb{R},r>0$ then $f\in C^{\infty}$

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral

I'm trying to show that if $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ is Lebesgue-integrable, has finite integral over intervals (i.e. $f\in L^1_{loc}$) and satisfies
$$f(x) = \frac{1}{2r}\int_{x-r}^{x+r}f(t)dt,\quad\forall x\in\mathbb{R},\forall r>0,$$
then $f\in C^{\infty}$.

The problem also suggests to first prove that $f$ is continuous and use the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus.

I conjecture that $f$ must be of the form $f(x) = ax + b$, but I haven't been able to prove it.

Comment: maybe try using the fact that $2f(x) = f(x-r) + f(x+r)$?

Comment: @Jkbb I think that I see where you are headed. How do you arrive to that conclusion? I have that $\int_{-r}^rF(t)dt=0$ for all x and r where $F(t) = f(x)-f(x+t)$. If $F$ is odd then the intregral is indeed $0$, but I need the reciprocal of that statement (if $F$ is odd then your claim follows).

Comment: $$f(x) = 1/4r \int_{x-2r}^{x+2r} = 1/2*1/2r[\int_{x-2r}^{x}+\int_{x}^{x+2r}] = 1/2[f(x-r) + f(x+r)]$$

Comment: Very clever, thank you :)